# Django admin nested inline without header

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm using https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline

Let's say my models are Top, 2nd, 2ndA and 2ndB.
Top and 2nd are one-to-many, while 2ndA and 2ndB are one-to-one with 2nd.

My app admin looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_inline.admin import NestedStackedInline, NestedModelAdmin
from myapp.models import Top, 2nd, 2ndA, 2ndB

class 2ndAInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = 2ndA
    extra = 1
    fk_name = '2ndA'
    template = 'admin/myapp/edit_inline/stacked-nested.html'

class 2ndBInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = 2ndB
    extra = 1
    fk_name = '2ndB'
    fieldsets = [
        ('Follow up notes', {'fields': ['followup_notes'],'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    template = 'admin/myapp/edit_inline/stacked-nested.html'

class 2ndInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = 2nd
    extra = 1
    fk_name= 'Top'
    inlines = [2ndA, 2ndB]
    template = 'admin/myapp/edit_inline/stacked-nested.html'

class TopAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    model = Top
    inlines = [2ndInline]

admin.site.register(Top, TopAdmin)
```

It works, but I'd like to get rid of the unnecessary headers like "2ndA: #1", as there will only ever be one entry.

I've tried overriding the template, but the moment I remove anything from within the h3 tags, it works for the first inline, but subsequent inlines don't seem to use my specified template, and instead somehow become tabular...

Thanks very much

Comment: Hi, @mcrsam. I got the same problem with you. Do you have any update on it? Many thanks :)